# Textbooks for understanding Cones and Conicoids in Analytical Geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am new to 3-D Geometry(Analytical Geometry) I am having difficulty in understanding Cones, Conicoids and Generating lines.
I could understand lines, spheres and planes with ease as I was able to visualize the shapes, but not so with the other figures
Can someone suggest a good text for understanding these subjects, preferably with shapes and diagrams

Answer (score 0):

You can use this book

> **Analytical Geometry Of Quadratic Surfaces , Kalyani Publishers**

Or this book

> *Analytical Solid Geometry by Shati Narayan*